# Android String color manipulation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have one text view in android which text is
"Hi how are you?"

My query is can we keep color of "hi how" as blue and "are you?" as red
in one line as below

[image: See this image]

cause now am using 2 text view to show "hi how" and "are you" respectively
but i want to show it in one text view with above requirement?

can we give two color code at a time to one text in String file?
any reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String text = "<font color=#0000FF>Hi How</font> <font color=#ff0000>are you</font>";
mTxtVw.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: u r welcome..you should accept one. as your answer so it help others while finding answer for your question

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you need a `SpannableString`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) the documentation

Comment: it seems to be we need to do it through java coding

is it possible to do in xml level??

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("hi how are you?");        

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```